# Infinity primes of the form $4k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a problem from the book *Introduction to algebra* by А. И. КОСТРИКИН.

> Assume $n,m\in \mathbb Z,\gcd (n,m)=1$. If $p$ is a prime and $p | (n^2+m^2)$, then $p=4k+1$. Use this to prove that there are infinity primes of the form $4k+1$.

My question is, why $p=4k+1$? It seems not so obvious to me. Also, I don't know how to use this to prove the proposition.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, this is quite well-known. Clearly, $m^{p-1}\equiv n^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ (why?). Suppose that $p=4k+3$ (note that $p=2$ is also possible). How can we now use $p\mid m^2+n^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

Remember Fermat's Little Theorem:

> $$a\not\equiv_p 0\Rightarrow a^{p-1}\equiv_p 1$$

And then consider:

> $$p\mid n^2+m^2\iff (mn^{-1})^2\equiv_p -1$$ This follows since $p\mid n^2+m^2\iff n^2+m^2\equiv_p 0$ by definition. Performing some algebra, we get: $$n^2+m^2\equiv_p 0\\m^2\equiv_p -n^2\\m^2n^{-2}\equiv_p -1\\(mn^{-1})^2\equiv_p -1$$

For the rest of the exercise, suppose that there are only finitely many primes $p$, such that $p=4k+1$, and let us name them $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$. Then, consider:

> $$N=4(p_1p_2\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n)^2+1$$

Comment: I am still confused that why $(mn^{-1})^2\equiv_p -1$ means $p=4k+1$

Comment: @FFjet try to make the exponent on the LHS $p-1$, and compare the RHS with Fermat's Little Theorem in mind.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get the point

Comment: @FFjet Raising both sides to the power of $\frac{p-1}{2}$ yields: $$(mn^{-1})^{p-1}\equiv_p (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$$ What is the LHS equal to? What can you then say about $\frac{p-1}{2}$, and therefore $p$?

Comment: Ok, I now understand.Thanks :D